# Java Moving JFrames Choppy Motion

Tags: java, swing, jframe, osx-mountain-lion

I have the following three classes:
Rndm:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Rndm {
    private static Random rn;
    public static String randInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return Integer.toString((min + (int)(Math.random()*(max-min))));
    }
    public static String randInt(int max)
    {
        return Integer.toString(((int)(Math.random()*(max))));
    }
    public static int intRandInt(int min, int max)
    {
         return (min + (int)(Math.random()*(max-min)));
    }
    public static int intRandInt(int max)
    {
        return (int)(Math.random()*(max));
    }
    public static String randString(int length)
    {
        String randstr="";
        for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)
        {
            int charset = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*3);
            if (charset==1)
            {
                char randChar = (char) (48 + (int)(Math.random()*(57-48)));
                randstr += randChar;
            }
            else if (charset==2)
            {
                char randChar = (char) (65 + (int)(Math.random()*(90-65)));
                randstr += randChar;
            }
            else if (charset==3)
            {
                char randChar = (char) (97 + (int)(Math.random()*(122-97)));
                randstr += randChar;
            }
        }
        return randstr;
    }
}
```

MovingWindow (a moving JFrame):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MovingWindow implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Point location;
    private Thread t;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int increment = 15;
    private int delay = 1;
    public MovingWindow(String tName) {
        t = new Thread(this, tName);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        drawFrame();
    }
    private void drawFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Moving Window");
        x = Rndm.intRandInt(70, 1000);
        y = Rndm.intRandInt(70, 1000);
        location = new Point(x, y);
        frame.setSize(500, 50);
        frame.setLocation(location);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        moveAround();
    }
    public void moveAround() {
        while(true) {
            int dir = Rndm.intRandInt(0, 9);
            switch(dir) {
                case 1:
                    quad1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    quad2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    quad3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    quad4();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    quad5();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    quad6();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    quad7();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    quad8();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    }
    public void quad1() {
        while (x<1000 && y<1000) {
            try { Thread.sleep(delay); } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {}
            setX(x+increment);
            setY(y+increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad2() {
        while (x<1000 && y>0) {
            try { Thread.sleep(delay); } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {}
            setX(x+increment);
            setY(y-increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad3() {
        while (x>0 && y>0) {
            try { Thread.sleep(delay); } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {}
            setX(x-increment);
            setY(y-increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad4() {
        while (x>0 && y<1000) {
            try { Thread.sleep(delay); } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {}
            setX(x-increment);
            setY(y+increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad5() {
        while (x>0) {
            setX(x-increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad6() {
        while (x<1000) {
            setX(x+increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad7() {
        while (y>0) {
            setY(y-increment);
        }
    }
    public void quad8() {
        while (y<1000) {
            setY(y+increment);
        }
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        location = new Point(x, y);
        frame.setLocation(location);
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
        location = new Point(x, y);
        frame.setLocation(location);
    }
}
```

and WindowManager (instantiates MovingWindow objects):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class WindowManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MovingWindow> windows = new ArrayList<MovingWindow>();
        for (int i=0; i<Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i++) {
            windows.add(new MovingWindow(Rndm.randString(10)));
        }
    }
}
```

The program behaves as expected until more than one frame is created. At that point, all but one or two frames slow down dramatically for a little while, resume moving normally for a few seconds, and then begin moving slowly again. I have a two part question:
1: Why is this happening?
2: How can I fix it?
I am running java 7 on OSX Mavericks.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that because of the way I wrote my program my movement will never be seamless, but why aren't all JFrames behaving the same way?

Comment: Rather than having a separate thread per frame, maintain a single thread that is responsible for the movement of all the frames...(and yes, a Swing `Timer` is prefered)

Comment: So make `WindowManager` a static class, remove the thread code from `MovingWindow`, change `Thread.sleep()` to use `Timer` instead, implement multithreading in `WindowManager`, and instantiate `WindowManager` from the class with the main method?

Comment: I don't know about making it `static`, you'd have to decide based on your needs, but basically, you should be passing either the reference of the Windows you want "controlled" or the number of windows it should create.  The `WindowManager` should then maintain a list of these Windows. On each iteration, you should walk this list and update the position of each Window. I'd avoid explicitly using `Thread` and instead use a Swing `Timer`...

Comment: Thank you this has been a lot of help. I will read more on EDTs and `Timer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling moveAround() from the main thread, and you're changing the GUI from there. That's a big no-no. All changes to the GUI have to be on the Event Dispatching Thread, or EDT.

However, you should never call Thread.sleep() on the EDT, so your current approach won't work.

I would look into using a Swing Timer instead.

Comment: I thought each new `MovingWindow`'s `run()` method would be run in a new thread. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Sure, and that's the problem. You shouldn't make changes to the GUI from a non-EDT thread, or you get weird errors like the one you're experiencing now.

Comment: @735Tesla Yes that is correct, but Swing is not thread safe and you should never modify the state of any Swing component from out side the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. You should also look at reducing the number of update threads you have...